# How to move lines of codes to the side (Left / Right) in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, move

Hi fella app developers,

I am going to move my selected codes (in bulk) in android studio to the side. I have been searching for a long time and I couldn't find an answer for it!!!

I know how to move them up or down or even individually move them to the side, but I am struggling to move whole codes in bulk.

Does anyone know how to do that???? It will be highly appreciated it.

Answer (score 6):

Select the code that needs to be moved, and press

```
Tab to move right
Shift+Tab to move left
```

Comment: Man you made my day! Thank you so muchhhhhhhhh